# Create the first component is a form field allow whole numeric values can be 1 up to 99 with no leading zero's allowed along with do not allow alpha

Tags: angular16, typescript-5

The component contains two separate angular material that will need to be combined in to one extended component. The first component is  a form field  allow whole numeric values can be 1 up to 99 with no leading zero's allowed along with do not allow alpha or special character to be added, the field is left blank the following validation should be display value must be between 1-99. There are two option to be available to select weeks and months but by weeks should be selected with light gray color and second component is button toggle weeks and Months from Calendar.

Enter the numeric value in mat input form field or copy paste or as per as the task acceptation is to be get the value from weeks and months from Calendar List.